# Large size query with PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

I've implemented a breadth first search with a PyMongo social network. It's breadth first to reduce the number of connections. Now I get queries like `coll.find({"_id":{"$in":["id1", "id2", ...]}}` with a huge number of ids. PyMongo does not process some of these big queries due to their size.

Is there a technical solution around it? Or do you suggest another approach to such kind of queries where I need to select all docs with one of a huge set of ids?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an inescapable problem, you could split the array of ids across multiple queries and then merge the results client-side.

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs majority of graph operations to be performed, prefer using a graph database like [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org).